# Laravel 5.1 Eloquent Many to Many Relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

Must I do database migration to be able to do Eloquent Many to Many Relationship or can I do it without database migration?

My tables are;

k_p_user and fields are; id,name,datee

k_p_tree and fields are; id,user_id,bear_id,name,datee

k_p_bear and fields are; id,user_id,name,datee

k_p_picnic and fields are; id,user_id,bear_id,name,datee

I am using netbeans 8.0.2

This is my Model for k_p_picknic

```
<?php namespace App
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class k_p_picnic extends Model{
}
?>
```

This is my controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\k_p_picnic;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request as Request;
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function fixoption($table){
        $gender=  k_p_picnic::all();
        dd($gender)
        return view('profile',['jj'=>$gender]);
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my error

> FatalErrorException in k_p_picnic.php line 8: syntax error, unexpected
>   'use' (T_USE), expecting \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) or ';' or '{'

Comment: No, You can use Eloquent without database migrations. [Laravel Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#introduction) _Migrations are like version control for your database, allowing a team to easily modify and share the application's database schema. Migrations are typically paired with Laravel's schema builder to easily build your application's database schema._ It has nothing to do with eloquent.

Answer (score 2):

No, migrations are not necessary for Eloquent relationships. Migrations just provide an easy interface in PHP for creating and maintaining database tables. There is no issue if you already have pre-existing database tables or an alternative way of creating them.

If you are confused about Many To Many relationships, make sure to read up on the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). For that relationship type, you will need a pivot table that contains the IDs for both models you want to connect. It appears as though your `k_p_picnic` table is that. Then you need to define each relationship on the model object. You can include a table name if you are not following normal Laravel table naming conventions. In your case, you are not, so just pass it in as the second argument. For instance, your User model would have this method:

```
public function bears()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Bear', 'k_p_picnic');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen then error

In my Model

instead of `<?php namespace App;`
I wrote `<?php namespace App`

Thank you all for your beautiful answers especially dipesh and Andy Noelker. i now know that i can have a pre-existing database that migration has nothing to do with Eloquent